# 'getTree': binary expansion of factor levels

Tags: r, binary-tree, random-forest

I am using the *randomForest* package and am trying to analyze the trees in the forest with *getTree()*.

"Details" for help(getTree) reads:

> For categorical predictors, the splitting point is represented by an integer, whose binary expansion gives the identities of the categories that goes to left or right. For example, if a predictor has four categories, and the split point is 13. The binary expansion of 13 is (1, 0, 1, 1)

Is the binary expansion a map to the factor levels? Can the order of the levels change from sample to sample that the forest does?

I need this in order to generate the partitions of every leaf (bucket) in every tree of the forest.

Thank you.

Comment: You should specify that you are using `randomForest` package. `getTree` is not a base R function

Comment: The next sentence continues: `... so cases with categories 1, 3, or 4 in this predictor get sent to the left, and the rest to the right.` I'm voting to close since the referenced help page contains the answer and there is no code in the question.

Comment: @BondedDust I continued to read the next sentence. It does not say explicitly 'levels' and the second part of the question is if the order of the levels fixed from sample to sample. If you can tell me how to verify that, I would be more than happy.